# How to find a document by looking for a match in an embedded document array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

This seems so simple but apparently I'm missing something.  I've got a WebSite model:

```
class WebSite
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :domains, inverse_of: :web_site
  field :name, type: String
end
```

The WebSite model has an embedded array of Domains:

```
class Domain
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :web_site, inverse_of: :domains
  field :name, type: String
end
```

All I'm trying to do is find a WebSite with a domain of "test.com".  Nothing I've tried seems to work, either with Mongoid or with the MongoDB console.  For example, if I have one WebSite, with one Domain, with the name "test.com":

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > WebSite.count
 => 1 
2.0.0p0 :002 > WebSite.first.domains
 => [#<Domain _id: 5148d9b76a3b8b1fe6000003, web_site_id: "5148d9a96a3b8b1fe6000002", name: "test.com">]
```

...then shouldn't this work?

```
2.0.0p0 :003 > WebSite.elem_match(domains: { name: "test.com" }).count
 => 0 
2.0.0p0 :004 > WebSite.elem_match('domains' => { 'name' => "test.com" }).count
 => 0
```

I get zero.  I should get one.

I also got the impression from the O'Reilly book that this should work:

```
2.0.0p0 :005 > WebSite.where('domains.name' => "test.com").count
 => 0
```

...same with any_in:

```
.0.0p0 :006 > WebSite.any_in('domains' => { 'name' => "test.com" }).count
=> 0
```

I've also tried those same queries from the MongoDB console with the same results:

```
> db.web_sites.find({"domains" : {"$elemMatch" : {"name" : "test.com"}}}).size();
0
> db.web_sites.find({"domains.name" : "test.com"}).size();                       
0
> db.web_sites.find({"domains" : {$in : {"name" : "test.com"}}}).size();
0
```

I must be missing something?

Update:

Here is some more information about the schema, from the MongoDB console:

```
> db.web_sites.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5148d9a96a3b8b1fe6000002"), "name" : "test" }
```

Comment: Please post the result of `db.web_sites.find().pretty()` such that one can get a better understanding of the structure of your data.

Comment: Okay, I updated the question with that information.  Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: You are searching for a document containing an attribute called "domains.name" with the value "test.com", but clearly this doesn't exist, hence no results are returned.

Comment: That's what I thought when I saw the output from pretty().  (Didn't know about that highly useful debugging trick, thanks!)  I just don't understand why Mongoid is returning an array for WebSite.first.domains.  I must be misunderstanding something about Mongoid.

Comment: OH!  D'oh!  I have two separate collections instead of an embedded collection.  Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to uldall's help with debugging (that awesome pretty() technique) I realized that my problem was that I had two separate collections side by side, instead of a Domain collection embedded in my WebSite collection.  This is how my models should have been set up, with "embedded_in" and "embeds_many":

```
class WebSite
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :domains, inverse_of: :web_site
  field :name, type: String
end

class Domain
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :web_site, inverse_of: :domains
  field :name, type: String
end
```

Now the document looks like this from the MongoDB console:

```
> db.web_sites.find().pretty()     
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5148e63f6a3b8b8ffa000001"),
  "domains" : [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5148e6706a3b8b8ffa000002"),
      "name" : "test.com"
    }
  ],
  "name" : "test"
}
```

With that schema, this works:

```
2.0.0p0 :008 > WebSite.where('domains.name' => 'test.com').count
=> 1
```

[CHEER]